# Is it possible to combine 2 neural networks?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a NET like (exemple from [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html))

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 5x5 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)  # 5*5 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Max pooling over a (2, 2) window
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        # If the size is a square, you can specify with a single number
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except the batch dimension
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
net = Net()
```

and another net like (exemple from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-tabular-binary-classification-a0368da5bb89))

```
class binaryClassification(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(binaryClassification, self).__init__()
        # Number of input features is 12.
        self.layer_1 = nn.Linear(12, 64) 
        self.layer_2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.layer_out = nn.Linear(64, 1) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.1)
        self.batchnorm1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.batchnorm2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        x = self.relu(self.layer_1(inputs))
        x = self.batchnorm1(x)
        x = self.relu(self.layer_2(x))
        x = self.batchnorm2(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.layer_out(x)
        return x
```

I'd like to change, for exemple "self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)" in order to have 121 inputs, where the 121th is the x (output) of the binaryClassification network.
The idea is: I'd like to use in the same time, CNN network, and not-CNN network, to train both, with influence one on the other.

Is it possible? How can I perform that? (Keras or Pytorch examples are both ok).

Or maybe the idea is crazy and there is easier way to mix data and image as input of an unique network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a perfectly valid approach, you are taking two different input data sources, processing them and combining the result to solve a common goal (in this case it seems like a 10-class image classification). You can define the input to your `Net` network to be a tuple of the `image` you need for the original `Net` and the `features` 12-value vector for your BinaryClassificator. An example code would be:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class binaryClassification(nn.Module):
   #> ...same as above

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 5x5 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)  # 5*5 from image dimension
        self.binClas = binaryClassification()        
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(121, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)
  
    def forward(self, inputs):
        x, features = inputs    # split tuple
        # Max pooling over a (2, 2) window
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        # If the size is a square, you can specify with a single number
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except the batch dimension
        # Concatenate with BinaryClassification
        x = torch.cat([F.relu(self.fc1(x)), self.binClas(features)])
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
net = Net()
```

However! Be careful about training them together, it is hard to balance both branches in the network to make them learn. I would recommend you to train them separately for a while before plugging them together (generally speaking, the hyperparameters of one part of the network will probably not be optimal for the other). To do this, you could freeze one part of the network while training the other, and viceversa. ([check this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-the-pytorch-freeze-network-in-some-layers-only-the-rest-of-the-training/7088) to see how to freeze parts of a torch nn)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your exemple let me understand a lot of things.
Can I ask you what do you think about `x = torch.cat([F.relu(self.fc1(x)), binClas_inputs])`?
I mean, don't have a binary classifier, but using its inputs as additional information of the "composed" network (instead using just the classification as asked in my first question).

Comment: I just spotted an error in my answer! it is now solved. W.R.T. your comment, it is yet another valid approach. You extract the features of the image and then run a classification using these features and the extra features of the binaryClassification_inputs. The advantage here is that you don't need to play with two sets of hyperparameters, the network should learn by itself the importance of each feature.

Answer (score 3):

The most naive way to do it would be to instantiate both models, sum the two predictions and compute the loss with it. This will backpropagate through both models:

```
net1 = Net1()
net2 = Net2()
bce = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
params = list(net1.parameters()) + list(net2.parameters())
optimizer = optim.SGD(params)
for (x, ground_truth) in enumerate(your_data_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    prediction = net1(x) + net2(x)  # the 2 models must output tensors of same shape
    loss = bce(prediction, ground_truth)
    train_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

You could also e.g.

- implement the layers of Net1 and Net2 in a single model
- train Net1 and Net2 separately and ensemble them later

Comment: Your solution requires both models to have the exact same output, which doesn't match with the OP's question. I believe the OP is asking for code to do one or both of the alternatives you give at the end (implement them both in a single model or train them separately and show code on how to ensemble them)